# How copy bootable partition to GPT-ed disk's partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, bootable-media

After messing up my Windows, at this moment (to say shortly), I have 256 GB HDD ( with `C:` 255GB  and `D:` 1GB partition).

I've made somehow efi-bootable USB-drive and if I plug the USB drive, then PC can boot (otherwise, "Invalid partition table" on booting). I've `sector-by-sector` copied USB to `D:` disk, but PC doesnt still boot without USB.

I've tried many things but i am unable to make the drive bootable... At this moment, I am now booted (with the help of USB) and how can I make a bootable partition?

Answer (score 1):

- Method 1: On start menu, click Power then hold Shift key and click on restart to get the option of troubleshooting startup, it’ll be straightforward and easy to understand what’s going on with your boot-up process
- Method 2: Make a bootable USB that contains a windows installation of the same version of Windows that you already have on your PC (e.g: windows 10 1903 64-bits) to troubleshoot startup errors on your disk

Answer (score 1):

If a bootable Windows partition has been copied to the disk C:, but you cannot boot
with it, then the boot code might be incorrect.

Create a USB installation media for Windows and use it to
[Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
to correct the boot. Read also the Note at the end of the linked article.

Comment: No, i had second hdd which booted, but i removed that hdd from pc.

Comment: The boot needs to be corrected on the disk that doesn't work.